# How to link library scalapack and blacs while compilation

Tags: fortran, scalapack, blacs

When compiling a fortran code, I set

```
FCL         = mpiifort -qmkl=sequential
LLIBS      += -L$(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64 -lmkl_scalapack_lp64 -lmkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64
```

but when compiling code, it always links to  `libmkl_scalapack_lp64.so`, not `libmkl_scalapack_lp64.a`. Then error appears,

```
ifort: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '-qmkl=sequential'
mpi.o: In function `m_max_d_':
mpi.f90:(.text+0x4b52): undefined reference to `dcopy_'
umco.o: In function `umco_mp_umco_calc_trafo_':
umco.f90:(.text+0x8c30): undefined reference to `dgetrf_'
umco.f90:(.text+0x8c69): undefined reference to `dgetri_'
umco.f90:(.text+0x8dde): undefined reference to `dgetri_'
umco.f90:(.text+0x9911): undefined reference to `dgeev_'
umco.f90:(.text+0x9aa4): undefined reference to `dgeev_'
mathtools.f90:(.text+0x3d08): undefined reference to `zgesdd_'
In function `w90_utility_mp_utility_zgemm_new_':
utility.F90:(.text+0x3712): undefined reference to `zgemm_'
/home/app/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.0.166/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_scalapack_lp64.so: undefined reference to `ssteqr_'
/home/app/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.0.166/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_scalapack_lp64.so: undefined reference to `dlahqr_'
```

What is the correct way to link these two libraries?

Comment: Please show more detsils, see [mcve]. Here, the whole compilation command that causes the error is important. And its complete output.

Comment: It is still not clear what ifort command was executed. But you are probably missing the main part of MKL that contains BLAS. Follow the Link Advisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends very much on what you are doing and compiler versions, amongst other things. As such you don't provide sufficient detail for us to answer the question. But the recommended way is to use the Intel link line advisor, which will help you find the answer by filling in all the required details into a web form. You can find this at https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/onemkl-link-line-advisor.html#gs.tephcr